# Does img src negate hover effects created in svg source code?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, svg, hover

I know how to create a hover effect on the tags in the svg source file but I'm wondering if using it as an img src tag negates the hover effects created in the source code of the svg?

the code is below.(heads up I am working in angularjs)

HTML

```
<div id="Slider">
        <img ng-repeat="x in lev.images" ng-src="{{x.src}}" />
      </div>
```

SVG

```
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{display:none;}
    .st1{display:inline;}
    .st2{
     fill:transparent;
     stroke:#000000;
     stroke-width:10;
     stroke-miterlimit:10;
     pointer-events:all;

    }
    .st2:hover{
        fill:#003057;
    }
</style>

<g id="Layer_2">
    <polygon class="st2" points="838.9,210.1 838.9,493.7 501,493.7 501,641.7 95.8,641.7 95.8,288.3 445.3,288.3 445.3,210.1  "/>
    <rect x="95.8" y="61.3" class="st2" width="349.5" height="227.1"/>
    <rect x="642.1" y="61.3" class="st2" width="196.8" height="148.8"/>
    <rect x="445.3" y="61.3" class="st2" width="196.8" height="148.8"/>
    <rect x="838.9" y="300.7" class="st2" width="150.3" height="193"/>
    <rect x="838.9" y="61.3" class="st2" width="150.3" height="239.5"/>
    <rect x="501" y="493.7" class="st2" width="488.2" height="148"/>
</g>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. You can't affect the internals of an actual **image** regardless of format with CSS. You have to affect **inline SVG/`<use>`**.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll look for another solution